# RoR resources: No action responded to 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following code to map my resources for my products controller:

```
     map.namespace :admin do |admin|
       admin.resources :products
     end
```

In my view I'm using

```
link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_product_path(product)
```

which results in the URL /admin/products/1/edit

when I'm clicking on the link I'm getting

Unknown action
No action responded to 1

So I guess it doesn't properly map it to the edit action.
I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The is route valid otherwise it'd be blowing up when you try to create your link. Does your product controller have an edit action?

Usually when I put a namespace in my routes it follows through to my controller and views. For example the full path would be

```
/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb

/views/admin/products/edit.html.erb
```

You'd also put a namespace in your controller too:

```
class Admin::ProductsController < ApplicationController
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have these lines in your routes file?

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

If so, make sure they are **below** your resource route lines. Those lines should always be near the bottom of your `routes.rb` because they are so generic. The more specific the route, the higher up it should be.